# Eclipse Maven Dependency issue

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have maven-depenencies folder which lists over 50+ jars I need for compile and testing on my local. In addition `POM.xml` have specific (see snippet) which lists the dependencies I wanted in "target/final_build.jar". I do not want rest of maven - dependencies I can see on eclipse IE. I just want following packaged as aprt of final jar..

What is the easy way to accomplish . I tried  copy-dependencies but it copied all Maven dependencies and not the 4 listed in pom.xml. More over they are copied over to lib/src folder.

Desired state is to just have 4 dependencies mentioned below are part of "target/outputfile.jar"

```
    <dependencies>           
       <dependency>
       <groupId>org.twitter4j</groupId>
       <artifactId>twitter4j-core</artifactId>
       <version>3.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.twitter4j</groupId>
       <artifactId>twitter4j-stream</artifactId>
       <version>3.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
   </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

Dependencies that are needed for compile/test but not for the application (because the (EE-/JDK-/?-) Container already have this classes) can be specified by the dependency scope **provided**:

```
<dependencies>           
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.twitter4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>twitter4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.3</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.twitter4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>twitter4j-stream</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.3</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: No. That is what exactly I want. I need them as part of JAR file built from this